# Google Sheets: Regex Expression for Phone Number Not Valid

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on capturing and removing phone numbers on a Google Sheet from a dataset of text.

Right now, I am trying

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/", " ")
```

Where the following:

```
    `You are submitting your information to Example, which powers
... suite 000 San Diego, CA 00000(123) 000-0000example@gmail.com.`
```

Should become:

```
You are submitting your information to Example, which powers ... suite
000 San Diego, CA 00000 example@gmail.com.
```

but Google says it is an invalid regex expression.
[stackoverflow is not letting me show the picture but here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6kR.png)

Explanation/expression will be really appreciated. The Phone numbers can be any of the following formats:

(123) 456 7899 (Preferred)

(123).456.7899

(123)-456-7899 (Preferred)

123-456-7899

123 456 7899

1234567899

Comment: You've used a backreference which is not supported in `REGEXREPLACE()`. Can't you simply use `\(?\d{3}\)?[\. -]?\d{3}[. -]?\d{4}` or would that catch too much?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74858657/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this case-insensitive [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regex that does not use backreferences:

`=regexreplace(A2, "(?i)\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]*\d{3}[-\s.]*\d{4}\s*(?:\(?preferred\)?)?(\b|[^\d])", " $1")`